# write a javascript method to update the textbox (or) any other control value using threading concept

Tags: javascript

I'm not getting the exact solution for this... Please help guys... Thanks in advance.

```
    function Variable(initVal, onChange) {
        debugger;
        this.val = initVal;          //Value to be stored in this object
        this.onChange = onChange;    //OnChange handler

        //This method returns stored value
        this.GetValue = function () {
            return this.val;
        }

        //This method changes the value and calls the given handler
        this.SetValue = function (value) {
            this.val = value;
            this.onChange();
        }
    }
    var myVar = new Variable(10, function () { alert("Value changed!"); });

    alert(myVar.GetValue());

    myVar.SetValue(12);

    alert(myVar.GetValue());
```

Comment: be more specific, I didn't get your problem.

Comment: what is your problem/question? as far as i see this seems to work.

Comment: Actually my question is:- in javascript ,in order to fetch the value of textbox,we use document . get Element By Id ("textbox Id")..ok...but here my requirement is to fetch the textbox value using threading..means i need to write a javascript method to get the value of any control using threading concept..but in net am not getting any clue about this....hoping for the solution